# error related to winrt::impl::com_ref<winrt::hstring> when converting from c++/cx to c++/winrt

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

In cppcx, I used to have this:

```
auto button = safe_cast<ContentControl ^>(obj);
if (auto text = dynamic_cast<Platform::String^>(button->Content)) {
    return text->Data();
}
```

When I try to do this to convert this code to cppwinrt:

```
auto button = obj.as<winrt::ContentControl>();
if (auto text = button.Content().try_as<winrt::hstring>()) {
    return text.c_str();
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error (active)    E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "winrt::impl::com_refwinrt::hstring" to "wchar_t*" exists

I was hoping I would get a winrt::hstring as a result of the try_as and I can get the .c_str() from it, but I am getting a winrt::impl::com_refwinrt::hstring instead. What am I missing?

Comment: Be thankful, the library just prevented you from returning a dangling pointer.

Comment: Is there no possible way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to unbox a scalar value behind an `IInspectable` interface (see [Boxing and unboxing scalar values to IInspectable with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/boxing)). For unboxing you'll want to use the [unbox_value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/unbox-value) function template:

```cpp
auto button = obj.as<winrt::ContentControl>();
if (auto text = unbox_value<winrt::hstring>(button.Content())) {
    return text.c_str();
}
```

Although it's questionable, whether you really want to return a pointer that points into the middle of some data owned elsewhere. It's probably best to just return an [`hstring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/hstring) by value. [String handling in C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/strings) has more information on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am finding it hard to understand both parts of this statement: "Although it's questionable, whether you really want to return a pointer that points into the middle of some data owned elsewhere."
and  
"It's probably best to just return an hstring by value. String handling in C++/WinRT has more information on the topic." 

Can you please elaborate? I cant make sense of the first part and can't seem to find which part of that link would help me get a hstring by value.

Comment: @ssn Make your function signature `hstring foo() {...}`, and in place of `return text.c_str()` just `return text`. Unlike returning `c_str()` this will make sure that the referenced string value stays alive for as long as you hold on to the `hstring`. Since C++ doesn't allow you to annotate pointers with information that would allow the compiler to track object lifetimes, you'll frequently come across dangling pointers. The `hstring` class conveniently solves this (and other) issues, much like C++' `std::wstring`.

Comment: I guess the problem is the caller of this function is cross-platform code which needs to understand the return value from all platforms. That's why I needed the return to be c_str()

Comment: @ssn If the caller is requesting a naked `wchar_t*` it **must** state ownership or lifetime requirements, either in documentation or code. Lacking that, you cannot write a correct program to interface with that caller. That's a different issue, though, and something you will have to negotiate with the caller of your implementation.